# Duda con filefilter de multer y manejo de erores

Tags: nodejs, json, express, postman, multer

Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva postman  un res.json cuando el archivo a subir no es el correcto? el código es el que pongo más abajo

Todos los ejemplos que he visto ponen esta opción :**cb(new Error('Error: La extension del archivo no es correcta. Tiene que ser jpg, jpeg, png o gif'));**

Si pongo el res.json, como veis en el código de arriba, como no esta en parámetros de la función me da error, y tampoco puedo ponerlo

Y en la ruta que es así **router.post("/upload", optionsFile, uploadEmpty)** Tampoco puedo poner el res

En postman me sale el error por defecto el del 500 con el html, y quiero que salga

**res.status(400).json({error: adjunta un archivo correcto, gracias})**

Alguien me puede dar una pista como hacerlo. Gracias

```js
const optionsFile = (multer({
  storage: storage,
  dest: path.join(__dirname, './app/uploads'),
  limits: {
    fileSize: 20000000
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif|svg|""/;
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
    if (mimetype && extname) {
      console.log('The file uploaded successfully');
      //res.send('The file uploaded successfully')
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    cb('Error: La extension del archivo no es correcta. Tiene que ser jpg, jpeg, png o gif');
  }
}).single('file'));
```

Estoy intentándolo solucionar con esto, pero me pone todo el rato que no encuentra archivo, que corresponde con el parámetro **uploadEmpety**, Quizá lo debería pasar dentro de un if como otro manejo de error?

```
router.post("/upload", uploadEmpty, (req, res) => {
  optionsFile(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'La extension del archivo no es correcta....'
      });
    }
    // else {
    //   // Todo ok, proceda con lo que tenga que hacer
    // }
  });
});
```

Comment: Por favor, el código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] para hacer los cambios necesarios, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Que es uploadEmpty?

Comment: Es una función que mira si hay un archivo para subir o no. Si no hay archivo dice que se ponga uno

Comment: Como lo has puesto lo he intentado hacer y me sale lo que tú dices. Probaré de ponerlo dentro el uploasEmpty, como otro manejo de error. Aunque creo que también lo intente y no me salía. Quizá me equivocaba en algo. Volveré a intentarlo. Gracias